# python 2.7 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: python-2.7

I am doing an exercise for an online course and keep getting an error thrown at me.  Theres another 404 error in the output as well actually.  I believe there are really only 2 spots where this could go haywire, line 11 and 13 but it looks correct to me.  If I replace the variables with fixed addresses (not user generated) it works fine.  Thanks for your help.

```
import socket

site= raw_input("Enter url:")
print ""
print "site is",site
print ""
hostel = site.split("/")
print "Hostel is", hostel
print ""
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((hostel[2], 80))

mysock.send('GET site HTTP/1.0\n\n')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(1024)
    data = data.strip()
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print data
mysock.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're not using your `site` variable here, but literally requesting "site":

```
mysock.send('GET site HTTP/1.0\n\n')
```

Try:

```
mysock.send('GET ' + site + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n')
```

Comment: Try to use a relative url in `send` instead of a full url, e.g. /code/romeo.txt

Answer (score 0):

You should use the variable 'site' instead of the word site try:

```
message_send = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n".format(site)
mysock.send(message_send)
```